# Permissions Denied error when trying to run a command via the authorized_key file

Tags: linux, security, permissions, openssh

I am trying to get a command to run via the `authorized_keys` file. I have set the perms to 600 for the `authorized_keys` file, and the `.ssh` dir to 700.

In the authorized file I have the following:

```
command="touch /home/borg/file.txt", restrict ssh-ed25519 <redacted>
```

Then I try to ssh to this host with:

```
ssh user@host.com
```

The user I am using is the same user that the `authorized_keys` file belongs to. I have tested the keys and verify that they do work and I am able to do a normal SSH to the host. It give s me a permission denied error when I try to add a command the file. I just can't for the life of me figure out what the issue is. Please any thoughts to help, I have tried `ssh -v` and I get the following at the end:

```
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/prod/.ssh/borg_key ED25519 SHA256:<redacted> explicit
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
borg@backup0.backup.server.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: “In the authorized file I have the following:” That stuff you state is in that file (`command="touch /home/borg/file.txt", restrict ssh-ed25519 <redacted>`) should not be in there. All that file should contain it the public key itself.

Comment: nope read the docs, it is a feature of limiting a public key access to a specific command.

Comment: **NO SPACE** between the comma ending the command option and the restrict option: `command="...",restrict {keytype} {blob}`. Note the words in man sshd: "... the following space-separated fields: options, keytype, base64-encoded key, comment". The space causes 'restrict' to be the keytype and 'ssh-ed25519' to be the actual key, and both are wrong; your actual key is treated as the comment field and ignored.

Answer (score 1):

NO SPACE between the comma ending the command option and the restrict option: command="...",restrict {keytype} {blob}. Note the words in man sshd: "... the following space-separated fields: options, keytype, base64-encoded key, comment". The space causes 'restrict' to be the keytype and 'ssh-ed25519' to be the actual key, and both are wrong; your actual key is treated as the comment field and ignored.

Comment: Please do not use other users' comments as your own answer. You can use a comment to get this author to write an answer and thus becomes his reputation.